# Take a Linux directory structure and turn it into a Sharepoint

Tags: linux

Using 2013 Sharepoint, can you feed sharepoint an existing Linux directory structure and have it create a Sharepoint out of it?

Obviously the permissions wouldn't apply, but is this do-able?

Answer (score 0):

You could import the directory structure with contents by simply copying through your file explorer. All SharePoint sites are accessible via WebDav. In OS X, you can use the Connect To Server command in Finder and enter the URL of your site collection. From there, you can copy any folder structures you like directly into SharePoint.